# How would you find equation of fourth line given three lines that form 3 sides of a square

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Say you are given the equations of three straight lines and they form almost a square (one side missing). Then you are asked to determine the equation of the last line to make the square
Well, I remember that the slope of the missing line is the the same as the parallel line but I cant figure out how to get the distances right

Answer (score 1):

You can find two corners by finding the two intersection points of the three lines you have.  The distance between the corners is the side of the square.  You can proceed the correct distance down the outer two lines to get the other two corners, then use the two point form for the fourth line.